# how to write function to target specific variable for ng disable that inside ng repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-disabled

I'm trying to build todo list app in angular. When you add new item, it will add to input box(by default, i set it to disabled) inside the table and also add Edit link next to that input. Once i click on the Edit, the input box will enable. ( i got it working with this code (Edit).

My question is how to replace ng-click="editable=!editable" with ng-click="edit()". I tried to write that Edit function, but i can't get it to work. Please help. 
[My code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sopanhanita/wnt3s07m/15/)

Thanks so much.

```
<body ng-app="shoppingList">
<div  ng-controller="mainController">
    <h1>My Shopping List</h1>
    <form class="form-inline" ng-submit="addItem()">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newItem">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add">   
    </form>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
                    <td><input ng-disabled="!editable" type="text" value="{{item}}"></td>
                    <td ng-click="editable=!editable">Edit</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>  
<script>
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('shoppingList',[]);
    app.controller('mainController',function($scope){
        $scope.items=[];
        $scope.addItem = function(){
            $scope.items.push($scope.newItem);
        };

    $scope.edit = function(){
    // i need to move editable=!editable into this function
    // but i don't know how to do that
    }

    });

}());
</script>
```

Comment: Your code [doesn't work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)?

Comment: @Robert, my code is working fine, but i need to replace ng-click="editable=!editable" with ng-click="edit()", because i need to use that edit() function to add more funtion. Thanks

Comment: Just declare  `$scope.editable = true;` like `$scope.items=[];` in the controller. But that is only a simple hack. Should the `editable` be specific to each line/row ? `$scope.editable= !$scope.editable; console.log($scope.editable)`

Comment: `editable=!editable` is just an evaluation that returns a bool. Write that in your edit function as `$scope.editable = !$scope.editable; return $scope.editable;`

Comment: @ Searching, yes the editable should be specific to each line/row. I tried with $index, but i can't get it to work. thanks

Comment: @Ronnie, i had tried $scope.editable = !$scope.editable; return $scope.editable; in the function, but the editable need to be specific to each line/row. i think i have to pass $index to that function, but i can't make it work.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the editable property of the `todo` item, and then us it like this.

```
$scope.addItem = function(){
    $scope.items.push({text: $scope.newItem,editable:false});
}; 

$scope.edit = function(item){    
   item.editable = !item.editable; 
   console.log(item)   
}
$scope.save = function(item){
  console.log("saved")     
   item.editable = !item.editable; 
 }
```

html

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
 <td><input ng-disabled="!item.editable" ng-blur="save(item)" type="text" value="{{item.text}}"></td>
<td ng-click="edit(item)">Edit</td>
</tr>
```

I think this is simplest one, but there is always a better approach. Let us know. What is [ngBlur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)

Comment: it's working like a charm. https://jsfiddle.net/sopanhanita/d8ke1jjk/9/
Thanks so much @Searching. i will learn from it.